# How can I get a request as text from curl?

Tags: http, curl

Is there a way to transform something like this:

```
curl https://some.api.com/$batch \
    -H "curl/7.9.8 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl 7.9.8 (OpenSSL 0.9.6b) (ipv6 enabled)" \
    -d '{ foo: ["bar" "baz"]}'
```

into something like this (handmade, there could be mistakes):

```
POST /$batch HTTP/1.1
Host: some.api.com
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: curl/7.9.8 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl 7.9.8 (OpenSSL 0.9.6b) (ipv6 enabled)
Content-Length: 21

{"foo":["bar","baz"]}
```

Ideally it'd be some command line option on curl, or I could live with some `nc` hack. Or is `--trace-ascii`  my best friend?